# efficient way to convert a nested list to numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a nested list with different list sized and types.

```
def read(f,tree,objects):

Event=[]
for o in objects:
    #find different features of one class 
    temp=[i.GetName() for i in tree.GetListOfBranches() if i.GetName().startswith(o)]
    tempList=[] #contains one class of objects
    for t in temp:
        #print t
        tempList.append(t)
        comp=np.asarray(getattr(tree,t))
        tempList.append(comp)
Event.append(tempList)

return Event



def main():
    path="path/to/file"
    objects= ['TauJet', 'Jet', 'Electron', 'Muon', 'Photon', 'Tracks', 'ETmis', 'CaloTower']

    f=ROOT.TFile(path)
    tree=f.Get("RecoTree")
    tree.GetEntry(100)
    event=read(f,tree,objects)
```

for example result of event[0] is

```
['TauJet', array(1), 'TauJet_E', array([ 31.24074173]), 'TauJet_Px', array([-28.27997971]), 'TauJet_Py', array([-13.18042469]), 'TauJet_Pz', array([-1.08304048]), 'TauJet_Eta', array([-0.03470514]), 'TauJet_Phi', array([-2.70545626]), 'TauJet_PT', array([ 31.20065498]), 'TauJet_Charge', array([ 1.]), 'TauJet_NTracks', array([3]), 'TauJet_EHoverEE', array([ 1745.89221191]), 'TauJet_size', array(1)]
```

how can I convert it into numpy array?

NOTE 1: np.asarray(event, "object") is slow. I am looking for a better way. Also np.fromiter() is not applicable as far as I don't have a fixed type

NOTE 2: I don't know the length of my Events.

NOTE 3: I can also get ride of names if it makes thing easier.

Comment: I would suggest you to give a look at `pandas` [`DataFrames`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html). I remember (hopefully correctly) reading somewhere that there is some support for columns of different length. Besides they support a number of numpy arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, I'm not sure how fast its going to be though. This creates a numpy record array for first row.

```
data = event[0]
keys = data[0::2]
vals = data[1::2]
#there are some zero-rank arrays in there, so need to check for those, 
#but I think just recasting them to a np.float should work. 
temp = [np.float(v) for v in vals]
#you could also just create a np array from the line above with np.array(temp)
dtype={"names":keys, "formats":("f4")*len(vals)}
myArr = np.rec.fromarrays(temp, dtype=dtype)

#test it out
In [53]: data["TauJet_Pz"]
Out[53]: array(-1.0830404758453369, dtype=float32)


#alternatively, you could try something like this, which just creates a 2d numpy array
vals = np.array([[np.float(v) for v in row[1::2]] for row in event])
#now create a nice record array from that using the dtypes above
myRecordArray = np.rec.fromarrays(vals, dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: I can't get this work. As I said I have list with different length. so when I have entry with different length than I mentioned here I get :
   temp2=[np.float(v) for v in vals]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
and even for this length I get :

  myArr = np.rec.fromarrays(temp2, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/records.py", line 537, in fromarrays
    descr = sb.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: It sounds like there are arrays in the rows with more than one element, i.e. something like ["TauJet_E", array([31.56, 45.14])]. That would reproduce the error  you see. Why would that be the case?

Comment: my code is exactly like I posted in the question! As I said the length of vectore can vary from one object to another when I am doing (comp=np.asarray(getattr(tree,t))) . so for example I may have:

'Jet_E', array([ 391.62017822,   31.24074173]), I fixed this using v.astype(float) but still I have problem with TypeError: data type not understood in last part

Comment: So what are the separate values when there are multiple values for a particle?

Comment: for example Electron_E with values [23,32,23] means we have three Electron we energies 23,32,23.

Comment: aha. Give me a bit and I'll see if I can get it into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I don't have permission to share any data. I ll appreciate your help

Comment: I don't think that a Numpy array is the way to go here, as the size of the elements are dynamic, and numpy arrays aren't really suited for that. You might be able to "pad" the other arrays with NaN's so that all of the arrays are the same size, i.e. the length of the longest array. It all depends on what you want to do with the data afterwords, but Numpy arrays are probably not the best data structure for nTuple data

Comment: I have already ask question in root_numpy. It still doesn't support vector elements. I will look more in pandas